# Get element by value after user input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple input elements and I'm trying to compare to another input by matching values.

The issue I'm having is I can't match values to the user input, though it works if both input I'm trying to compare already have values after page load.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4zabsa9e/9/)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="list" value="1">
<input type="text" class="list" value="2">
<input type="text" class="list" value="3">
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="a" class="find" value="">
<input type="text" id="b" class="find" value="">

<button id="trigger">Click Me</button>

<script>
$(document).on('click', '#trigger', function () {
    $('.list').each(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var match = $('input.find[value="'+value+'"]').attr('id');
        alert(match);
    });
});
</script>
```

**EDIT**

I guess I should've pointed out that I'm looping through the first set of input values and checking through multiple user input so I can retrieve the id of the matching user input. Updated my code and fiddle

Comment: just to clarify : You want to compare and match values from two text fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: It looks like you were looking for a more flexible solution than my original one.

I implemented it using [`jQuery#each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

```js
$('#trigger').click(function() {
  $('.list').each(function() {
    var value = this.value, match
    $('.find').each(function () {
      if (this.value === value) {
        // found a match!
        match = this.id
        return false
      }
    })
    console.log('value:', value, 'match:', match)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="list" value="1">
<input type="text" class="list" value="2">
<input type="text" class="list" value="3">
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="a" class="find" value="">
<input type="text" id="b" class="find" value="">
<button id="trigger">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Sorry this won't do. I updated my question. Thanks for your help

Comment: Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Run on each of the inputs and compare by value

```js
    $('#trigger').click(function () {
      var a = $('#a').val();
      $('input.find').each(function(){
       if (this.value === a )
         alert(this.id);
      });
    });
```

```html
 


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="text" id="a" value="13.4">
    <input type="text" id="b" class="find" value="13.4">
    <input type="text" id="c" class="find" value="13.2">
    <input type="text" id="d" class="find" value="13.4">
    <button id="trigger">Click Me</button>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4zabsa9e/6/)

EDIT: I assumed that you want to compare with more then one input with the class `find`

Comment: `.find` values should be user input and I can't run `.each()` on `.find`. I updated my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```js
$(function(){
    $('#trigger').click(function () {
        var a = $('#a').val();
        var b = $(".find");
        if(a === b.val()){
            console.log('match found with id:'+b.attr('id'));
        } else {
            console.log('not any match found');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="a" value="13.4">
<input type="text" id="b" class="find" value="">
<button id="trigger">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: this is nice though when I add multiple input i'm only getting the first `id` when there's a match.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to compare values use equality (`==`), use  identity (`===`) in case to compare value as well as type like string, int etc.

```js
$('#trigger').click(function () {
  var a = $('#a').val();
  var b = $('#b').val();
  if(a==b)
  alert("matched");
  else
  alert("not matched");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="a" value="13.4">
<input type="text" id="b" class="find" value="">
<button id="trigger">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`jQuery.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) like this:

```js
$('#trigger').click(function() {
  var val = $('#a').val();           // get the value of #a input
  var inputs = $("input.find");      // get all the other inputs (the ones that have the class find)

  inputs.removeClass("green");
  if (val.length) {                  // if the value of #a is not empty
    inputs.filter(function() {       // filter out all the inputs that have the same value
      return $(this).val() === val;
    })
    .addClass("green")
    /*
    .each(function() {
      alert(this.id);
    });
    */
  }
});
```

```css
.green {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="a" value="13.4">
<input type="text" id="b" class="find" value="">
<input type="text" id="c" class="find" value="">
<input type="text" id="d" class="find" value="">
<button id="trigger">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this --

```
$('#trigger').click(function () {

    var a = $('#a').val();
    var match = $('input[value="'+a+'"]').attr('id');
    alert(match);
});
```

Comment: you just copied my previous code and just removed the class.